# Swift is it possible to set a specific country for MKLocalSearchRequest and MKLocalSearchResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder if its possible to set a country for MKLocalSearchRequest and MKLocalSearchResponse in mapKit?

In my map view the user can search for a zip/state. But I don't want to show hits in other countries since it would not make any sense here.

Thanks in advance,

```
localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "23138"
        localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in



            if localSearchResponse == nil || self.mapView == nil{
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: nil, message: "Place not found", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
                alert.show()
                return
            } else {

                let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


                let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)


                self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = location
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pointAnnotation)
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While there doesn't appear to be a way to explicitly constrain an `MKLocalSearchRequest` to a specific geographic context, you can get pretty close with the following steps:

1. Set the search request's `region` property to an `MKCoordinateRegion` corresponding to the USA (unfortunately, Alaska and Hawaii make the region rather large; depending on your application, you may want to use just the continental USA).
2. In your callback handler, you can filter the `MKMapItem` array returned from the `MKLocalSearchResponse` by their `placemark` properties' `countryCode` property, to only use those whose country code is `"US"`.

If you're not getting the kind of results you'd like, you can investigate other third-party API services, to see if any of those would be more suitable for your specific use case.

Comment: I can seem to find those properties that you mentioned. I updated my question with my current code as well :) Thanks

Comment: the `CLPlacemark` properties are exactly the properties to filter. These are the same properties that Google Places API uses as filter parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution requires to run the search for every element just after the `MKLocalSearchCompleter` has provided the completions for the request - this will be throttled by Apple to max 50 requests every 60 secs